# DHCP configuration for iPXE

Tags: dhcp

Is there a way to configure the DHCP process in iPXE? In particular, I want to configure the DHCP Discover message **sent by iPXE**, so that the message issued by iPXE includes more options in Parameter Request List (Option 55) for the server to replied with. Currently, only a restricted subset of options are requested, but I want more.

Comment: May be DEFINING NEW OPTIONS section of `man dhcp-options` is what you want? http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-options

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear. But what I want is to configure iPXE to issue its DHCP discover message to include more options, so my DHCP server can give out those options in its response message.

Comment: Sorry, can't help, never used iPXE.

Comment: I know this is an old question but might still be worth clarifying what the request is/was... You want to change which options iPXE itself requests, not only forcing which options the DHCP server sends (which would be the normal way to do it by detcting iPXE option 175) 
The only way to do that seems to be by modifying the `dhcp_request_options_data` in `/src/net/udp/dhcp.c`